# Is reading uppercase sentences hard?

Tags: typography, reading

When there's an uppercase sentence, I've found it's hard to read easily. Is it just me or do others also experience this?

Comment: No, it isn't just you, although it may be challenging for an answer to dig up the appropriate research to supply an authoritative reference as to why

Comment: I think two facts to face it one is maybe  habitually we read lowercase sentence that's way or it is something about illustrating and confusing brain.

Comment: I THINK IT'S BECAUSE ALL CAPS CAUSES A LOT OF VISUAL CLUTTER, MAKING IT DIFFICULT TO CONCENTRATE ON WHAT YOU'RE READING. I THINK THIS WOULD BE A BETTER QUESTION FOR THE PSYCHOLOGY STACKEXCHANGE SITE, THOUGH, AS IT DEALS LESS WITH ENGLISH AND MORE WITH VISUAL PERCEPTION

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about English.

Comment: It may be off-topic but it is certainly very useful. Yes, it's very hard to read. So it all lower case. What ins't hard to read are regular sentences with regular punctuation. if you see what i mean

Comment: Yes, all upper-case is referred to as "SHOUTING", and it is generally disliked by the people who must read it, since it is harder to read and parse.

Comment: Disadvantage of SE is people just say off topic and so on. That's not helpful really. They put ideas on where to ask but it wouldn't helpful always. Some are my questions off-topic everywhere. So just try to help with question if you could.

Comment: Not refuting anyone's opinion, but I just think this proposal is entirely not true as Uppercase alphabets are used in popular Media `(Memes, E-Commerce platforms` etc.. It may take me some time training and Practice to be acquitted with Label Tennis

Comment: This **may** be on-topic on [CogSci.SE]. But do check their help pages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the paper [Reading Text from Computer Screens](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.513.2691&rep=rep1&type=pdf) cites studies that found that uppercase sentences are read more slowly and with lower comprehension than sentences with normal casing (links added):

> When the task involves reading continuous text from paper, however, there is generally superior performance with lowercase letters. For example, [Tinker [1955]](http://psycnet.apa.org/journals/apl/39/6/444/) reported that text in all uppercase letters retards reading speed by 10.2-14.2% compared with text in combined uppercase and lowercase letters. [Poulton and Brown [1968]](http://psycnet.apa.org/index.cfm?fa=buy.optionToBuy&id=1968-06242-001) found comprehension scores were lower for text in all uppercase letters than for the normal uppercase and lowercase combination. For rapid continuous reading, [Tinker [1963]](https://books.google.com/books?id=xvILAQAAIAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=uppercase) concluded that combined upper- and lowercase English texts are read more rapidly and are preferred by readers over texts all in uppercase.